# How to find distance given candela values on a coordinate system?

Tags: optics, visible-light

Consider this diagram:

[image]

Let's say that some lamp at 1.5D, 2R has a luminous intensity of 35,000 cd. I want to find the maximum distance at which this lamp can put 5 lux on the road.

I understand that candela, lux, and distance are related as such:

$$ E_v = 10.763 × \frac {Iv}{d^2} $$

Solving the above equation gives ~275 feet. 35,000 candela can put out 5 lux of illumination at 275 feet.

Now, let's say I want to calculate the 5 lux illumination distance of this theoretical lamp while it's mounted on a vehicle.

Would the 275 feet value be the hypotenuse of the right triangle I set up below?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No. The base of this right triangle (you have labelled "road") will be the distance at which that point in the beam, 1.5D, intersects the road surface. With a more or less typical passenger car lamp mount height of 0.69m, your 35,000-candela hot spot at 1.5D will strike the road at 26.35 m, or just shy of 86.5 feet.